# is there any difference in using instance variables in a Rails controller other than visibility in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tend to mix local variables and instance variables in Rails controllers when I don't need to use them in a view. Obviously, if I'm using in the view, I use instance variables. Is there any difference between using them in that scenario (other than class-level visibiity)?

For example:

```
  def destroy
    @micropost.find(params[:id])
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

or

```
  def destroy
    micropost.find(params[:id])
    micropost.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

an example of using instance variables for class level visibility would be here: https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/blob/master/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb ?

Answer (score 1):

I think [these lines of code](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/blob/master/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb#L16-L27) is what your question about. Of course you don't have to instantiate that variable with `@` since you are not actually going to show it on your view(since it is being destroyed). The purpose of these lines of code if to first check wether `@micropost` exists, if it does not then [`redirect_to root_path`](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/blob/master/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb#L25) else it will go to [`destroy`](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/blob/master/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb#L16-L19) method destroy the micropost and then [`redirect_to root_path`](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/blob/master/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb#L18).

Now, to answer your question, yes, there is a huge difference between `@micropost` and `micropost`. `@micropost` will be accessible in other methods of your controller while `micropost` will not(since its scope will be limited to the method you instantiate it in).

However, if you're concern about not having a `@` variable then you can change the [code shown here](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/blob/master/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb) to this:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      micropost.destroy
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside, scope difference, you can access instance variable in another method of same controller, as

```
def method1
 @var = "some value"
 puts @var
end

def method2
 puts @var
end
```

now, depending on the sequence u call these method, @var can have different values